# Azure Mobile Services and Blob

Tags: ios, html, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-blob-storage

I'm developing an app with both web based admin UI (html5/JS sdk) and iOS app (using iOS Azure sdk)

Now I have a requirement to store gallery images. I know one way of doing is saving base64 in db, but it's not feasible and not a good practice.

So I was experimenting ways to upload images to blob storage and store the url in the mobile service table. As far as I can see there is a [C# tutorial](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/upload-images-to-storage-wp8/) but nothing much on html5 apps. Can someone point me to a correct resources.

I tried to implement it using this tutorial, but it just talks about setting the [sass url](http://chrisrisner.com/Mobile-Services-and-Windows-Azure-Storage)

Any tips or helps appreciated. Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Now that [`Windows Azure Storage supports CORS`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2013/11/27/windows-azure-storage-release-introducing-cors-json-minute-metrics-and-more.aspx), it is certainly possible to interact with blob storage directly from HTML 5 Apps.

First thing you would need to do is enable CORS on your storage account. My company released a **free tool** (its .Net based) which you can use to manage CORS rules. You can read more about the tool and download from here: http://blog.cynapta.com/2013/12/cynapta-azure-cors-helper-free-tool-to-manage-cors-rules-for-windows-azure-blob-storage/.

Once you do that, you may find these blog posts useful:

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/12/01/windows-azure-storage-and-cors-lets-have-some-fun/ (Scroll down to the section titled `Web Application` to see the code for uploading files directly into blob storage using HTML 5/JavaScript).

http://gauravmantri.com/2013/02/16/uploading-large-files-in-windows-azure-blob-storage-using-shared-access-signature-html-and-javascript/ (slightly older post, but you can use the source code for uploading ... this one's useful when you're uploading really large files).

Comment: awesome, I'll check it out and get back here. Thanks alot :)

Comment: I'm getting this kinda errors XD http://pastebin.com/9AHZMjfs

why microsft has to complicate things. May be I should go with S3

Comment: Can you describe the CORS rule settings you have set?

Comment: I placed all permission (get, del etc etc) and set allowed headers to content-type. nothing much.

Comment: Were you able to figure out a solution to your problem? What I found is that you would need to set 3 types of request headers in CORS rule: content-length, accept, and x-ms-* (x-ms-* would take care of all request headers start with x-ms-). HTH.